# sum of series $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Does there exist an explicit formula for the sum of the series

$$\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$$

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642906/simplify-triangular-sum-of-triangular-numbers-sum-i-1n-frac12ii1).