# Having trouble with a Binomial proof by mathematical induction question: $\sum_{j=3}^n \binom{j-1}{2} = \binom{n}{3}$

Tags: summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

I can't work out how to prove this equation is true by proof of mathematical

Use mathematical induction to prove that, for $n \ge 3$

$$\sum_{j=3}^n \binom{j-1}{2} = \binom{n}{3}$$

Please help, thanks

Comment: An easier combinatorial argument:  Count how many three-element subsets there are of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ 1) Directly 2) By breaking into cases based on the largest element appearing.

Comment: Related: [Hockey Stick Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof of the Hockey-Stick Identity: $\sum\limits_{t=0}^n \binom tk = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1)

Comment: The original question did ask for you to prove something similar to Hockey-Stick identity. $\binom{n}{r} + \binom{n}{r+1} = \binom{n+1}{r+1}$ before this equation

Comment: Some other related posts: [Evaluate $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k(k+1)$ combinatorially](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/43317) and [Simplify triangular sum of triangular numbers: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac12i(i+1))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1642906). Also other posts [linked to the latter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1642906) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $$\sum_{j=3}^n \binom{j-1}{2} = \binom{n}{3}$$ is true. Let's prove 
$$\sum_{j=3}^{n+1} \binom{j-1}{2} = \binom{n+1}{3}$$
So
$$\sum_{j=3}^{n+1} \binom{j-1}{2} = \sum_{j=3}^{n} \binom{j-1}{2} + \binom{n}{2} =  \binom{n}{3}+ \binom{n}{2} = \frac{n!}{3!(n-3)!}+\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!} = \frac{(n+1)!}{3!(n-2)!} = \binom{n+1}{3}$$

Comment: You can't assume true for the original equation, I'm trying to prove that the original equation is true.

Comment: @HarryMichaelKirwan that's how induction works. You assume that it  is true for $n$ and prove that it being true for $n$, implies it is true for $n+1$. You must also prove that it is true for smallest possible value of $n$. In this case that is $n=3$.

Comment: @HarryMichaelKirwan, I could have told you it is true for $n-1$, then i'd do the same steps to prove it for $n$. Try it yourself !!!

Comment: @AhmadBazzi actually yeah my bad sorry, but what I don't understand is where you got the $\binom{n}{2}$ going from $\sum_{j=3}^{n+1} \binom{j-1}{2} $

Comment: what is $\binom{j-1}{2}$ computed at $j = n+1$ ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Yes I understand now... the ending term of the sum will be that. Thank you